# Java class instance recursive calling

Tags: java

I have a very basic java theory question. Why the Employee class calls its self recursively in the following example?

```
class Employee {

Employee emp = new Employee();

}

public class Manager extends Employee {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Manager mgr = new Manager();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're instantiating an Employee class whitin your Employee class, which instantiates its own Employee class, which instantiates its own Employee class, etcetera. This question means you lack fundamental understanding of object oriented software. Re-read the basics :)

Comment: Why you place your second line, the `Employee` create, is it because you thought you have to create it, in order to have inheritance hierarchy or it's by choice, a composition, you want each Employee to have a reference to another employee? Maybe we can help you further.

Comment: @Dennisch I think it should be very clear to you from my question that I lack fundamental understanding that's why i asked the question.I read this example in a book but i didn't understand the explanation. Thanks to Jesper for such detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what the code is doing:

When you create a new `Manager` object, the `Employee` part of that `Manager` object is also going to be initialized (because `Manager` extends `Employee`).

When the `Employee` part is initialized, its `emp` member variable is going to be initialized. It will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. But that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. And that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. And that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. And that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. And that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. And that object also has an `emp` member variable, which will be initialized with a new `Employee` object. ... etc. until the stack overflows.

Comment: Note that he doesn't create an Employee in his code. He creates a Manager only. So his question is not about the recursion but about inheritance.

Comment: But `Manager` extends `Employee`, so the `Employee` part of the `Manager` object will also be initialized, leading to the recursive loop.

Comment: Best explanation, although it should start like  *When you create a new `Manager` object, you create a new `Employee` object, when you create a new `Employee` object, its emp member variable is going to be initialized. It will be initialized with a new Employee object. But that object also has an emp member variable, which will be initialized with a new Employee object...*

Comment: Thanks guys, I added some info on how the `Employee` part of the `Manager` object is going to be initialized.

Comment: @Jesper, I got it now... how it works, Thanks very much for such an excellent explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Skip the commented object creation, every time you create an `Employee` which happens when you create `Manager` because it inherits it, it enters an internal loop.

```
class Employee {

//Employee emp = new Employee();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
}
```

What this means is that each `Employee` contains an instance of another `Employee`. As such, when your `Employee` is constructed, it also has to create the `Employee` it contains. However, by the same logic, that `Employee` must also have its own child `Employee` that must be constructed, and so on.